# What is the physical meaning of multiplication of two wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition

In the amount of quantum mechanics I'vs learnt I understand what wave functions are, how do we extract information from them and so on, and that *addition of two wavefunctions on renormalization gives a **superposition** of the corresponding quantum states.*

I was learning the completeness of hermitian operators when I came up with the question as to what does the multiplication of 2 wavefunctions mean physically, if anything at all??

Please note while answering that I still don't completely understand what **completeness** really means and what is it's significance is although our professor did tell us it will be really useful *later* .

The equations are as follows :

$\int(\phi_{i}^*) (\phi_j) dx= \delta_{ij}$

$\delta_{ij}=1$ for i=j  ,  $0$  otherwise

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Inner_product

Comment: I don't think $\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x)$ really has much meaning outside of the integral you're performing. Now, as for the meaning of the _integral_, that's quite a long story but you can think of it as a generalisation of a dot product.

Comment: @jacob1729 I kind of know parts of that long story. But it really is nothing more than a mathematical manipulation that helps us solve easily for the respective $a_i$ values of the different mutually independent wavefunctions that in turn help us find various system parameters right **?**

Comment: @jacob1729 you can write multiparticle states as $\phi_1\phi_2\dots\phi_n$.

Comment: @Triatticus could you please elaborate on **what multiparticle states are** , **what do they mean physically** and **how are they useful?**

Comment: @Triatticus those are functions of multiple variables $\Phi(r_1,r_2,\dots,r_N)=\phi_1(r_1)\dots\phi_N(r_N)$. That's not the same sort of thing that occurs here.

Comment: @jacob1729 that might be so but it's still the same type of idea, that a multiparticle system can be written as a product of wave functions of each particle.

Comment: @user14812745 a multiparticle system is a system with multiple particles, ie like higher Z atoms or molecules. For example a He atom or a water molecule.

Comment: @jacob1729 so given the wavefunctions are of two different particles, their multiplication represents the combined system??   And it's just a mathematical trick to find out the respective probabilities of each state in case the wavefunctions are independent wavefunctions of a given state(as per the comments on the other answer to this question) ???

Comment: @user14812745 That's roughly correct (with caveats), but the two things aren't especially related. The most important caveat is that multiparticle states do not have to factorise, those that do are actually pretty special, but a generic state can be expanded in product states much like a signal can be expanded into Fourier components even if it  isn't a pure frequency.

Comment: @jacob1729 okay, correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I understood the multiplication of the wavefunctions of two separate particles will definitely represent the combined system while not every multiparticle system needs to be such that we can express it as a product of the wavefunctions of the separate states ??  **or**    is it that the product may not always represent the combined system(but it does in some special cases ) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really mean anything physically (as far as I know.)  Rather, it's a mathematical trick that allows us to explicitly figure out how to write any wavefunction $\psi$ as a superposition of some set of eigenstates $\phi_n$.

Specifically, the property of **completeness** says that any wavefunction $\psi$ can be written as some superposition of the eigenstates:
$$
\psi = \sum_j a_j \phi_j
$$
for some set of complex coefficients $a_j$.  The **orthogonality** property is then
$$
\int \phi_i^* \phi_j \, dx = \delta_{ij}
$$
(note the complex conjugate, though if the wavefunctions are real you can ignore it.)

These two properties allow us to extract the coefficients $a_i$ for an arbitrary wavefunction $\psi$, as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int \phi_i^* \psi \, dx &=\int \phi_i^* \left[ \sum_j a_j \phi_j \right] \, dx \\
&= \sum_j a_j \left[ \int \phi_i^* \phi_j \, dx \right] \\ 
&= \sum_j a_j \delta_{ij} \\ 
&= a_i.
\end{align*}
So if you tell me that the wavefunction at some time is $\psi$, then I can figure out exactly what superposition of the eigenfunctions it is by doing a bunch of integrals.   Knowing the coefficients $a_i$ then allows me to figure out the probabilities and expectation values of measurements, or (if the eigenstates are energy eigenstates) to use the time-independent Schrödinger equation to find how the state $\psi$ evolves in time.

Comment: Ok, so that completeness part is nothing more than a mathematical manipulation that will  ease my life as a physicist when I'm trying to find the respective wave functions that my $/psi$ is a superposition of, right? Also, what will I do with that information??

Comment: @user14812745:  Yes, it's basically just an extremely useful mathematical property of Hermitian operators and their eigenstates.  As far as what to do with this information, I've edited my answer to add a bit more information at the end.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't a superposition always of equal energy states and hence the energy will be the energy of any one eigenstate without consideration of $a_i$ ??  I could be wrong, this is a deduction I've made from examples.

Comment: @user14812745:  No, you can have a superposition of any two states, regardless of whether their energies are the same or not.  In such an instance, the relative probability of measuring a particular energy will be proportional to the absolute square of the corresponding $a_i$ coefficient.

Comment: So sir, we **won't be able to define absolute energy** of the state represented by the superposition?  And will only be able to say about the **probability of the system having a particular value of energy?** The probability being $a_i^2$ .

Comment: @user14812745:  That's correct.  Such a state will not have a definite energy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using asterisks for multiplication, which is not a good idea when writing equations for other humans. In this context, it also creates confusion because it looks like the notation $z^*$ (with a superscripted asterisk) for the complex conjugate of a complex number. In fact, that's particularly relevant here because your equation as written is incorrect. One of the $\phi$'s has to have its complex conjugate taken.

The integral $\int \phi_i^* \phi_j dx$ is called the inner product of the two wavefunctions. It has the interpretation that it measures how similar they are in terms of overlap. For example, if one of the wavefunctions is the wavefunction of an electron that's totally localized within an atom in my house, and another one is for an electron that's totally localized within an atom on the moon, then this integral will be zero because there's no overlap. This tells us that the two states are completely different, and they can be 100% distinguished in a one-shot measurement.

As a geometrical analogy, this is all closely analogous to the vector dot product.

Comment: @user285844 Hey, sorry for the error have corrected it, could you please tell me more about the use of this **completeness** . My attempts at the same have failed many times.